# Token based Authentication & Authorization not Working WebApi and Angular SPA

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am creating a SPA using Angular and WebApi and i am implementing token based authentication into this, but seems like its not working.

**Here is the StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           var publicClientId = "self";
            var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(publicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin")
            };
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(oAuthServerOptions);
        }
```

Code for SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs

```
var authService = container.TryGetInstance<IAuthService>();
                    if (authService != null)
                    {
                        User user = await authService.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                            return;
                        }
                        var authIdentity = await authService.UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                        var cookiesIdentity = await authService.UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                        var properties = CreateProperties(user);
                        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(authIdentity, properties);
                        authIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
                        authIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
                        context.Validated(ticket);
                        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
                    }
```

RESPONSE

```
{access_token: "OnG0zg8MVofhPEkkFvkBBHqAG3npYGexA6od-krMuenpVVMeJZ…tP1vR2UmT1qCv4nEoKYKWh8-OAYBc6I-FiEWezYIALPUIjV8U", token_type: "bearer", expires_in: 86399}
```

seems fine so far for me. but when i try to hit a WebApi HTTPGET method getting
401 (Unauthorized). And **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** always remains **false**

I am not understanding where i am doing wrong..

[image]

Comment: You need to store your token locally and resend it on every request in `Authorization` header. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes i am doing that...

Comment: i updated the question attached screen shot of detailed Request information

Comment: @KhanhTO Can you check that...thanks